# Electricity source for magnetoplasmadynamic engines in KSP

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm attempting to create some cool long distance ships with the new hydrogen+electricity engines but quickly realized how ridiculous these engines are in terms of electricity intake. I managed to use the Power Distribution Unit from a Mod that stores 120,000 electric charge but even then, the large LF-9 Engine takes up nearly 3000 charge per second! Normal solar panels are almost useless if I want to sustain the engine for long periods so my question is, are there better electricity harnessers than the large stock solar panels? Maybe some mod with crazy nuclear reactors that produce massive amounts of power?

Comment: What mods are you currently using?  Magnetoplasmadynamic engines don't exist in the stock game.

Comment: @MBraedley [Near Future Propulsion](http://near-future-technologies.wikia.com/wiki/Near_Future_Propulsion), I guess.

Comment: Yeah, sorry shoulda mentioned that. Near Future Propulsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Are there better electricity harnessers than the large stock solar panels?* There are: [Near Future Solar panels](http://near-future-technologies.wikia.com/wiki/Near_Future_Solar) can provide some power.

*Maybe some mod with crazy nuclear reactors that produce massive amounts of power?* Yep, [Near Future Electrical](http://near-future-technologies.wikia.com/wiki/Near_Future_Electrical) would be the first choice for sun independent systems or when you need even more power.

The [Near Future packs](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/52042-0-25-Near-Future-Technologies-) are almost likely intended to be used together.